# Is there a way to copy the bits from a double into a uint64 without type conversion or memory spilling?

Tags: c++, casting, type-conversion

Let's say that I have

```
uint64_t x = 0x3ff0000013300000;
double y;
```

I want to give y the bits x has; essentially assign y = x, except no floating-point conversion should take place, so that at the end of it, y will be equal to 1.0000000714790076.

I know that

```
y = reinterpret_cast<double*>(&x)[0];
```

will accomplish this task, but what I'd like to know is if this can be done in C++ without spilling to memory.

Comment: What is it that you call "memory spilling"? Also note that, no matter how you are going to do it, it will *technically* be undefined behaviour, even if you assert that the two types have the same size.

Comment: At this point, someone ought to be asking you _why_ you have these specific requirements.  Possibly [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: I have these specific requirements because I have Cryptographic Hash Function that has a double-floating-point operation in the middle of a bunch of integer operations, with no floating-point conversion taking place on the bits.  There is no point in second-guessing what it is I want here.

Comment: "There is no point in second-guessing what it is I want here" but there is a point in asking you to make your requirements much clearer.

Comment: @MNagy: Since what you want is a) undefined behaviour and b) platform-dependent (and the answer to your question title is, hence, "no, not legally"), it is highly questionable that you have understood that piece of code / algorithm correctly. Which, *especially* in the field of cryptography, does not bode well for whatever it is you're trying to do... no offense intended. We're trying to help here.

Comment: Could you clarify how what I'm trying to do is undefined behavior?  I'm effectively attempting to do a memcpy, but ideally with more assurance that there will be no fetches from memory.

Comment: @DevSolar https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Register_allocation#Spilling  he's concerned the compiler is actually going to store y separately from x, from what I understand.

Comment: @MNagy: Transferring a bit pattern from one type to another is well-defined for any type `T` to `unsigned char[]` and back to type `T`, no more. Any other conversion may e.g. result in an invalid object state, trap representation etc.; it's one of these things that usually work but are outside the realm of what the standard guarantees. The standard doesn't mention registers at all... and if your intention is to refer *to the same register / memory location* as both `uint64_t` and `double`, that would be breaking strict aliasing rules as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as you are absolutely certain that `sizeof(double)` is the same as `sizeof(uint64_t)` on your platform, you can use `std::memcpy`.

```
uint64_t x = 0x3ff0000013300000;
double y;

static_assert(sizeof(x) == sizeof(y));
std::memcpy(&y, &x, sizeof(y));
```

Comment: memcpy causes a memory spill

Comment: @MNagy and what is that?

Comment: It means it requires a fetch from memory, which tends to have a high latency.  I would prefer it if what I does not stray from the current registers.

Comment: @MNagy: It is completely up to your CPU architecture whether it is even possible to copy from an integer register directly to a floating point register.

Comment: @mnagy are you absolutely certain memcpy will have the behavior you describe?  Many compilers will elide the memcpy completely in simple cases, depending on target architecture.

Comment: It certainly can, depending on how many other things are present in the code.  It probably wouldn't if it were just the toy example I gave, however in a larger context with more active state there is a real possibility that it will cause a fetch from memory.  This seems like the best answer I'm going to get, however.

Comment: throw in a `static_assert(sizeof(uint64_t) == sizeof(double));` just to be safe...

Comment: @MNagy This is where you write assembly instead of c++.

Comment: @xaxxon, excellent suggestion.

Comment: Realistically, even if it it's architecturally impossible to copy the bits from an integer register to a FP register, the spill will be to L1d cache. There's no C++ problem here; the speed of this whole operation will be dominated by CPU architecture. And yes, this could very well be slow, precisely because it's such a rare operation. CPU architectures are optimized for common operations, and the speed of uncommon operations is pretty random.